# Android Studio, call a public method [ message() ] from MainActivity to AlarmReceiver

Tags: java, android, android-studio

## MainActivity.java

This is my MainActivity class

i want to call the message() to different java class.

```
package com.example.shyeilla.myapplication;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
TimePicker alarmTimePicker;
PendingIntent pendingIntent;
AlarmManager alarmManager;



public void message()
{
    final EditText etText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etText);
    Button bEnter = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bEnter);


    bEnter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), etText.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

   }
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    alarmTimePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);


}

public void OnToggleClicked(View view)
{
    long time;
    if (((ToggleButton) view).isChecked())
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ALARM ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarmTimePicker.getCurrentHour());
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarmTimePicker.getCurrentMinute());
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

        time=(calendar.getTimeInMillis()-(calendar.getTimeInMillis()%60000));
        if(System.currentTimeMillis()>time)
        {
            if (calendar.AM_PM == 0)
                time = time + (1000*60*60*12);
            else
                time = time + (1000*60*60*24);
        }
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, 10000, pendingIntent);
    }
    else
    {
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ALARM OFF",   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

}
```

## AlarmReceiver.java

This is the AlarmReceiver Class

```
MainActivity class1 = new MainActivity();

class1.message();
```

Not Working

This is the code of AlarmReceiver

```
package com.example.shyeilla.myapplication;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.Ringtone;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;


public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
@Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{

    MainActivity class1 = new MainActivity();
    class1.message();
    Uri alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
    if (alarmUri == null)
    {
        alarmUri =       RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    } 
    Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, alarmUri);
    ringtone.play();

}
}
```

No ToastMessage Appear Please Help me Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can I ask what do you want to do?

Comment: I just want to display the Toast Message from TextBox inserted by user in AlarmReceiver but nothing happens

Comment: I want to call the message() to AlarmReceiver Class

Comment: You should never instantiate an `Actiivity` class yourself, the Android framework should do this using `Intents` like `startActivity(myIntent);` - You should pass the message inside the onReceive intent.  However since you want the current edit text input this may not be the same as when the alarm intent was wrapped into a pending intent.  Use another Broadcast Receiver in your Activity and send a local broadcast in AlarmReceiver to the Activity BroadcastReceiver so you can access editText and show the toast message. Remember to register and unregister the Receiver in your Activity.